# Creating custom fields with django-filters

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a model as shown below. The model has the attribute `type` as a foreign key.

```
class YachtGeneralInfo(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(
        YachtTypes,
        related_name="yachts_in_type",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    ....
    ....
```

I wrote a view class like this -

```
class YachtGeneralInfoView(ListAPIView):

    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
    serializer_class = YachtGeneralInfoSerializer
    filter_backends = [OrderingFilter, SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = [
        "status",
        "is_professional",
        "chartered_with__id",
        "harbour__id",
        "harbour__city__id",
        "model__id",
    ]
    search_fields = ["name", "company_name", "website", "owner__name"]
```

I would like to add another filter for field `type`. However, I want to provide multiple values for this query parameter like `[1,2,3]`.

If I do that directly with queryset then it would be like this -

```
queryset = YachtGeneralInfo.objects.filter(type__in=[1,2,3])
```

Is there a way I could write a custom filter set field to accomplish this instead of having it directly in the queryset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your custom filter set for the type id look-up.

```
class YachtTypeFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    type_in = django_filters.CharFilter(
        method='filter_guest_level', field_name='guest_level')

    def filter_type_in(self, queryset, field_name, value):
        if value != "":
            id_array = json.loads(value)
            if isinstance(id_array, list):
                return queryset.filter(type__id__in=id_array)
        return queryset
```

Then you can set that class in the view.

```
class YachtGeneralInfoView(ListAPIView):
    ...
    filterset_class = YachtTypeFilterSet
```

Comment: Thanks, David, I had a question though. What does `filter_guest_level ` & `guest_level ` means. DO I have to replace the values as per my use case? What values would go in the method and field name? I believe the field name would be `type` but not sure what method would be.

Comment: Also will `filterset_fields` &  `filterset_class` would work in the same APIView?

Comment: Yeah, I think so.